# How to merge the branch with no changes into master branch in git?

Tags: git, github, git-branch, git-merge, branching-and-merging

Having a basic doubt in git branching and merge .
Can a branch be merged without any changes into master . If so , What happens to the delta changes that exists between master and branch . Will that be overridden with master branch changes . Refer the below scenario :

I have two branches master and BugBranch.

STEP 1:

```
C--B--A   (master)
      |
      X   (branch)
```

Took a branch from master say BugBranch .
Now I have a file TestMerge.java.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
...
...
callSomeMethod();
  switch(decision)
  {
    case A:
        do_something
        break;
    case B:
        do_something
        break;
  }
}
```

So at STEP 1 , both master and BugBranch looks same.

STEP 2:
The file(TestMerge) is changed in master as below . ( just removed the switch )

```
public static void main(String[] args){
...
...
callSomeMethod();
}

C--B--A--1  (master)
      |
      X     (branch)
```

STEP 3:
The problem is when I try to merge the branch with the master . Expecting a merge conflict in file , since there exists a delta for sure and want to preserve the changes in BugBranch . But the strange thing is that , its getting overridden with the master changes .

Tried out the below commands

> git checkout master
>
> git merge BugBranch

This is really confusing !

Comment: Did you do any changes with this file on BugBranch?

Comment: There is no deltas in Git. Each commit is full snapshot of working directory. And branch is only a pointer to commit, noting more. So, if you just branch from `master`, then there is no `X`, branch `BugBranch` will point to commit `A`. And when you merge commit `A` into commit `1`, it is no-op, since commit `A` is already part of history for commit `1`.

Comment: Did you do any change on branch `X` (the BugBranch)?

Comment: If it's unclear what everyone is saying, `X` and `A` are the exact same commit. When you merge you therefore just fast forward X to be the exact same as 1.

Comment: Not a single change is made in BugBranch. But the file is changed in master branch in rev "1" .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A Git branch is just a pointer to a commit. The `X` branch in your question points to commit `A` and for many Git operations, `X` can be used instead of `A` and vice-versa and you get the same result.

Only by its creation, a Git branch does not produce any change in the repository. Until you do some changes in the files and commit them, the branch does not diverge from its source branch (`master` in your case).

You change some files and committed on `master` (commit `1`). If you didn't change and commit anything on branch `X`, it still points to commit `A` which is in the history of branch `1` (actually, it's its parent).

When you want to commit branch `X` into branch `master`, Git detects that the branch `X` is in the past of branch `master`; starting from `master`, if Git repeatedly jumps from one commit to one of its parents it can reach the commit pointed by branch `X` (which is the `A` commit).

This means the branch `X` doesn't contain anything that is not already in branch `master`. In other words, there is nothing to merge and Git informs you about this situation with the message "Already up-to-date.".

On the other hand, if you want to merge `master` into `X`, because `master` is in the future of `X`, Git transforms the merge operation into a "fast-forward" operation. This means, it doesn't create an unnecessary new merge commit and just pushes the `X` branch (the branch you merge into) forward until it reaches the `master` commit (the branch you merge from).

You can force Git to create a merge commit by using the `--no-ff` flag in the [`git merge`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge) command line but, except for really exceptional situations, you don't have any reason to do it. It produces a commit that doesn't introduce any change in the files.

Comment: Yes --no-ff also says **Already up-to-date** . So basically its no point in merging those two branches , since both of them are same commit ?

Comment: It depends on the direction of the merge (`X` into `master` doesn't produce anything new, `master` into `X` should fast-forward `X` to `master`). Use [`git branch -v`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch) to find out if both branches point to the same commit. Or better try a GUI Git client and visually inspect the situation.